# How to integrate OAuth2 with back- and frontend

Tags: django, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm learning OAuth2 to integrate a 3rd party provider like Facebook or Github. But I'm struggling with finding resources that describe how to integrate it when you're building an app with both a back- and frontend.

In this example, let's pretend a have frontend (`myfrontend.com`) running something like Vue.js. And a backend (`mybackend.com`) running something like Django. And a 3rd party provider like GitHub.

My idea is to use this flow:

1. Front end redirect's to providers Authorize url. example: `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https://mybackend.com/callback?return-to=https://myfrontend.com/home`.
2. If the user authorizes, backend receives `code` in `/callback`.
3. Backend sends authentication request (serverside) with `code` to get `access_token` to 3rd party provider.
4. Backend creates a user if it doesn't exist yet and saves access_token associated with that user.
5. Backend creates a new local token for the user (for authenticating to mybackend.com) (JWT or OAuth2).
6. Backend redirects to `https://myfrontend.com/home` (specified in first url) with token in body.
7. Frontend receives token and saves in in local storage.
8. When the frontend requires a resource from GitHub a behalf of the user, a request is sent to my backend which in turn uses the save access_token and requests the resource from GitHub.

My question is this:

- Is this flow safe or should I reconsider?
- in step 6, do I have to make sure that redirect-url is to my domain `myfrontend.com`. Feels like it would leave a security flaw if you check this in a bad way.

Comment: Do you know that there are django packages that do a third party authorization: django-allauth: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html; django-social-auth: https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html ?

Comment: Yes, i will use them, but they're not really plug and play if your not using the Django Templates and have a frontend framework instead.

Comment: In short, the safe bet would be to use an existing solution (instead of building your own), and there are standard solutions as for Django, as for DRF.

Comment: Can I ask you (if you know). Is it most common for the FE to sent the original access token from the provider (Facebook, GitHub) to the BE that verifies it with the provider.
Or, authenticate again to the BE and exchange the token for a new one.

Using the package linked below, you can do either. https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2